# Error - input that isn't a symbolic tensor - Boolean

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to adjust the weights of a `Dense` layer thanks to a binary crossentropy loss. A have created a shared layer that output for two vectors two values (`encoded_value_1` and `encoded_value_2`). I want to create a boolean equal to 1 if the value of `encoded_value_1` is superior to the value of `encoded_value_2`.
In order to do that I use `greater` via a `Lambda` layer. Yet, it produces an error (see below).

```
import keras
from keras.backend import greater
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Lambda, concatenate
from keras.models import Model

value_1 = Input(shape=(4,))
value_2 = Input(shape=(4,))

shared_layer = Dense(1)
encoded_value_1 = shared_layer(value_1)
encoded_value_2 = shared_layer(value_2)

x = Lambda(greater,output_shape=(1,))((encoded_value_1,encoded_value_2)) 
model = Model(inputs=[value_1, value_2], outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy'])
```

NB: I also tried to concatenate the two layers, I had the same error.

```
merged_vector = concatenate([encoded_value_1, encoded_value_2], axis=-1)
x = Lambda(greater,output_shape=(1,))((merged_vector[0],merged_vector[1]))
```

> ValueError: Layer lambda_4 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [(, )]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three points:

1. When the `Lambda` layer has more than one input, then the inputs must be passed as a list of tensors, not a tuple.
2. The output of `greater` is a bool Tensor which you need to cast to float for doing computations on it.
3. `greater` takes two inputs, so you need to wrap it inside a python `lambda` function to be able to use it in a `Lambda` layer in Keras.

Therefore, we would have:

```
from keras import backend as K

# ...
x = Lambda(lambda z: K.cast(K.greater(z[0], z[1]), K.floatx()),output_shape=(1,))([encoded_value_1,encoded_value_2])
```

And also don't forget the missing opening bracket for `metrics` argument:

```
..., metrics=['accuracy'])
             ^
             |
             |
          missing!
```